# Filtrar consulta de datas mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

tenho essa tabela mysql:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE 1 = 1
AND data_prova >= '2020-03-01'
AND data_prova <= '2020-03-26'
```

Pois bem, com esse select uso para um filtro e era para me retornar as três ultimas linhas, mas ele só me retorna o do dia 02-03 e 24-06, o dia 26-03 não retorna, qual o erro?

O campo `data_prova` é do tipo `datetime`, e a data estou colocando como string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não informou o horário junto com a data hora. Com isso ele assume o padrão "00:00:00.000" para o horário.

Tente:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE
 data_prova >= '2020-03-01 00:00:00.000'
AND data_prova <= '2020-03-26 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: Vlw, resolveu sim. Mas por conta de não usar os minutos apenas coloquei o `date` antes dos campos assim: date(hp.data_prova) pra ele entender que quero apenas a data. Muito obrigado!